# Random item from the array without repeating elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, random

I don't want the function to repeat elements taken from the array

```
function Gen() {
    let Qu = ["Yazeed", "Ammar", "Marwan", "Othman", "Sameh", "Amro", "Ibraheem"];
    let p1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
    let text = " ";
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {  //Qu.length = 7
            let p = Qu[Math.floor(Math.random() * Qu.length)];
            text+= "This is " + p  + "<br>";
    }
    p1.innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: shuffle and pop

Comment: Or shuffle and shift()

Comment: @YazeedZaid See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61556262/2813224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `splice` to remove the item from the array after displaying it.

If you don't want to alter the array, then you can create a copy before altering it.

```
let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * Qu.length);
let p = Qu[id];
Qu.splice(id, 1);
text += "This is " + p + "<br>";
```

Working code:

```js
function Gen() {
  let Qu = ["Yazeed", "Ammar", "Marwan", "Othman", "Sameh", "Amro", "Ibraheem"];
  let p1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
  let text = " ";
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) { //Qu.length = 7
    let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * Qu.length);
    let p = Qu[id];
    Qu.splice(id, 1);
    text += "This is " + p + "<br>";
  }
  p1.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo1"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="Gen()">Generate</button>
```

Comment: Yes. As mentioned it will alter the array. You can create a copy of the array before altering

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shuffle function based on the [Fischer-Yeats algorithm](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/). It swaps with a temp variable and decrements from the length.

```js
let names = ["Yazeed", "Ammar", "Marwan", "Othman", "Sameh", "Amro", "Ibraheem"];

function shuffle(array) {
  let qty = array.length, temp, i;
  while (qty) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * qty--);
    temp = array[qty];
    array[qty] = array[i];
    array[i] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}

document.querySelector('output').textContent = shuffle(names);
```

```html
<output></output>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I've been helpful

```
function Gen() {
    let Qu = ["Yazeed", "Ammar", "Marwan", "Othman", "Sameh", "Amro", "Ibraheem"];
    var QuNew = Qu.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5); // <- Make new random array 
    let p1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
    let text = " ";
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {  //Qu.length = 7
            text+= "This is " + QuNew[i]  + "<br>";
    }

    p1.innerHTML = text;
}
```