# Show result from array one item for one time ( Not Same Item any more)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, arraylist

I set a copy button in my code. The function is when user click copy button a random item from list will be copy.
its works fine. But my problem is I want different item each click... ( not same as any previous item)

My random pic item code is

```
var myArray = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3','name4', 'name5', 'name6', 'name7', 'name8', 'name9', 'name10'];

function copyFunction() {
  var rendtxt = myArray[~~(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
  const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textArea.textContent = rendtxt;
  document.body.append(textArea);
  textArea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  button.innerText = "Text copied";
  textArea.remove();
}
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', copyFunction);
```

You can check output [here](https://ahosanmonzil.blogspot.com/2022/06/copy.html)

Comment: Shuffle the array randomly at the beginning. Then pick the next one each time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to efficiently randomly select array item without repeats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891173/how-to-efficiently-randomly-select-array-item-without-repeats)

Comment: also [Random item from the array without repeating elements in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61556115/random-item-from-the-array-without-repeating-elements-in-javascript)